# Select the most appropriate technique and describe the solution for calculating the sum of the even numbers in a given list

Tags: algorithm, greedy

"Select the most appropriate technique and describe the solution for calculating the sum of the even numbers in a given list"
It seems like an easy question but I'm stuck. By technique it means backtracking/divide and conquer/greedy/dynamic programming.

I thought the answer would be greedy? Is this correct? And I have to describe the set of candidates and how I make the selection for the greedy algorithm.

I thought that we should simply iterate through the list, see if the each element is even. If an element is even, then we add it to the sum. This is not a backtracking/divide and conquer or dynamic programming approach, so it is greedy. So at the start, the set of candidates for the greedy algorithm is each element of the list. We select each time the first element in the set of candidates and we remove it from the set. And then we check if it is even. And the solution function will indicate when we have discovered a complete solution when the set is empty. Is this correct?

Comment: At the minimum level, you should try to provide what you've tried/researched, and where do you got stuck?  And your description is very ambiguous - how do you calculate the `sum` of the even numbers?  What's your possible inputs/outputs?...

Comment: My problem is that the solution to this question seems very simple, so I don't know how it would fit into any of these programming techniques.

Comment: I thought that we should simply iterate through the list, see if the each element is even. If an element is even, then we add it to the sum. This is not a backtracking/divide and conquer or dynamic programming approach, so it is greedy. So at the start, the set of candidates for the greedy algorithm is each element of the list. We select each time the first element in the set of candidates and we remove it from the set. And then we check if it is even. And the solution function will indicate when we have discovered a complete solution when the set is empty. Would this be alright? @DanielHao

Comment: Yes, it does seem like a trivial task. So either A) you've misquoted the question, or B) the question is flawed.

Comment: Let f(l) be the sum of even numbers in l, you can define `f(l) = (head(l) if l is not empty and head(l) is even else 0) + f(tail(l))`.